# heap polution, java

Tags: java, generics

```
List l = new ArrayList<Number>();
List<String> ls = l;       // unchecked warning
l.add(0, new Integer(42)); // another unchecked warning
String s = ls.get(0);      // ClassCastException is thrown
```

The java documentation says;

> > Furthermore, a heap pollution situation occurs when the l.add method
> >     is called. The **static type second formal parameter of the add method
> >     is String, but this method is called with an actual parameter of a
> >     different type, Integer**. However, the compiler still allows this
> >     method call. Because of type erasure, the type of the second formal
> >     parameter of the add method (which is defined as List.add(int,E))
> >     becomes Object. Consequently, the compiler allows this method call
> >     because, after type erasure, the l.add method can add any object of
> >     type Object, including an object of Integer type

my question is about the part i made bold. I understand that in line 2 heap pollution occurs cause l being of List references an object of type List. But when add method is called on l reference shouldn't it expect Number type instead of String as l is reference to ArrayList. Or is it, that after ls=l the space in heap is made of `List<String>` also for the l reference? in this case makes sense what java docs says in the part made in bold

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But when add method is called on l reference shouldn't it expect Number type instead of String as l is reference to ArrayList.

`List l` is just declared as an untyped List. So the compiler will let you put in whatever you like (and warn about it), and let you assign it to an incompatible `List<String>` variable (and warn about it).

If you said `List<Number> l`, the compiler would enforce the proper types (and not let you assign it to `ls`).

No matter what generic types you declare or not declare, this has no effect at runtime. To maintain backwards compatibility, generics are a complete compile-time-only feature.

> Or is it, that after ls=l the space in heap is made of List also for the l reference??

If you say

```
List l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<String> ls = l;
Object x = ls;
Collection<?> c = (Collection) x;
```

you have four different variables (with four different type declarations), but they all point to the same data (the same object on the heap).

Comment: thanks! so u say that if the situation was like was this: List<Number> l =  new ArrayList<Number>(); List<String> ls = l; compiler wouldnt give unchecked warning and would give directly an error. But what about type erasure then? After it List of Numbers becomes List and List of Strings becomes LIst also, so compiler should let do ls=l; Its really weard...://

Comment: @tomaas The compiler is guaranteeing type-safety for you. At runtime there is no type-safety at all, but that doesn't matter because the compiler made sure that the **code** is type-safe.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the first line. You declared `l` as a non type-safe list. Replace your first line by this:

```
List<Number> l = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider, what does the compiler know about this line:

```
l.add(0, new Integer(42));
```

It knows it has l, what it l? it's

```
List l
```

no specification of what type it can take. The line

```
List<String> ls = l;
```

has no effect on l, it is not the cause of the symptom you ask about, it's showing a different kind of problem.

Comment: Yes. I see that but in java docs, the part i made in bold as u can read, says that l.add() should expect String. It is so confusing..thank u

Comment: I think you should read the bold sentance as meaning "l is referencing an object that wants to be called with a String second parameter, however l itself is of a more general type, and hence the compiler cannot and must not enforce that rule, the compiler can only enforce that the second parameter is something an List can deal with."